# Upload file to S3 with Node.js

Tags: amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 using multer-s3, but got `AccessDenied` Error. Here I configure aws service:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY_ID,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    dirname: '/images',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    },
  }),
});
```

Even if I defined this policy for my User:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You can use the `Policy Generator` tool to create the policy: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html and also make sure that your `IAM` profile has the required access (`AmazonS3FullAccess`).